# CSS background-image not loading in some pages

Tags: html, css

My background image only appears in one page and not in the other page. I'm using the same CSS code for both, but only one seems to be working.

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
   padding-top: 40px;
   padding-bottom: 40px;
   background-image: url('img/background.jpg'); 
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Screenshots of the pages:

[background image loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtsPP.jpg)

[the background image not working for this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w84FB.jpg)

Comment: Are the two pages at the same level in the directory structure? Do you need to add `base_url` to the `img/background.jpg`?

Comment: Can you please include your code properly, the code seems incomplete. Link it to a demo.

Comment: Could u post the source code of second page where the above css is not working.

Comment: Change background-image: url('img/background.jpg');  to background-image: url('<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/background.jpg');  Hope this helps

Comment: Hi  ranjeet for your info it is web based application on intranet not internet. I use wamp server and the files are stored in wamp/www/mpkj/application/ view--- all interface file in php script with html script. My image is stored in local computer wamp/www/mpkj/img/background.jpg – user2655325 8 hours ago   delete

Answer (score 0):

Your second page may have problems finding the img you want as background, and because of that it cannot use it. Try placing both of your HTML-documents and the image you want as background all in the same folder if you have not already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Yuor issue is that the page almost certainly can not find the image.

Your background states:

```
 background-image: url('img/background.jpg');
```

Which in effect is saying:

```
background-image: url(<curent HTML page directory>/'img/background.jpg');
```

**THIS IS A BAD WAY TO REFERENCE RESOURCES**

Because the reference is not absolute, as you are experiencing, the reference is *relative to your current location on the website*. Yes, your pages load the same CSS file, but the CSS file uses the directory of the HTML page which
calls it, and *not* it's own storage directory.

To fix this and make this backgound work no matter which website page you are on, you need to give the CSS an **absolute** image reference. Absolute references start with a slash `/` which denotes the base of the website URL see `http://www.sitename.com/ <==` This end slash here has equality with the base slash.

So,

```
background-image: url('/img/background.jpg');
```

Now means

```
background-image: url(<website base directory>'/img/background.jpg');
```

Which in effect means:

```
background-image: url('http://www.sitename.com/img/background.jpg');
```

And will work no matter which page, in which folder calls this CSS file. As long as this absolute path reaches a valid image file, the file will be loaded by the CSS.

Comment: Thanks. Its work with background-image: url ('http:://localhost/mpkj/img/background.jpg');
But my problem now is this application is web based and run on the local host. It is installed in the workstation. With this coding work fine in workstation but when i run from other pc connected in the network, background does not loaded.
This may cause by the path and the location of the image. What should i do to make the application rum exactly as in the workstation with background?

Comment: @user2655325 use base directory referencing as I have stated in my answer. so your background image URL is `/img/background.jpg` assuming `mpkj/` is your website root.

Comment: For your info it is web based application on intranet not internet. I use wamp server and the files are stored in wamp/www/mpkj/application/ view--- all interface file in php script with html script.  My image is stored in local computer wamp/www/mpkj/img/background.jpg